# How to pass not variadic values to fmt::format?

Tags: c++, formatting, variadic-functions, variadic, fmt

I'm playing with the great [fmt C++ library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) to format strings more gracefully.

And I'd like to pass a non-variable arguments list to `fmt::format`. It could be a `std::vector`, or `std::string`, or whatever, but it will always match the format string.

So `fmt::format` works like:

```
std::string message = fmt::format("The answer is {} so don't {}", "42", "PANIC!");
```

But what I'd like is something like:

```
std::vector<std::string> arr;
arr.push_back("42");
arr.push_back("PANIC!");
std::string message = fmt::format("The answer is {} so don't {}", arr);
```

Is there a way / workaround to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an extra layer, something like:

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
std::string my_format(const std::string& format,
                      const std::vector<std::string>& v,
                      std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return fmt::format(format, v[Is]...);
}


template <std::size_t N>
std::string my_format(const std::string& format,
                      const std::vector<std::string>& v)
{
    return my_format(format, v, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

Usage would be:

```
std::vector<std::string> arr = {"42", "PANIC!"};
my_format<2>("The answer is {} so don't {}", arr);
```

With `operator ""_format` you might have the information about expected size at compile time

Answer (score 9):

You can build up the arguments to `vformat` on your own from your `vector`. This seems to work:

```
std::string format_vector(std::string_view format,
    std::vector<std::string> const& args)
{
    using ctx = fmt::format_context;
    std::vector<fmt::basic_format_arg<ctx>> fmt_args;
    for (auto const& a : args) {
        fmt_args.push_back(
            fmt::internal::make_arg<ctx>(a));
    }

    return fmt::vformat(format,
        fmt::basic_format_args<ctx>(
            fmt_args.data(), fmt_args.size()));
}

std::vector<std::string> args = {"42", "PANIC!"};
std::string message = format_vector("The answer is {} so don't {}", args);
```

Answer (score 3):

In the current version (8.1.1) the following is possible;

```
fmt::dynamic_format_arg_store<fmt::format_context> ds;

ds.push_back(42);
ds.push_back("PANIC");

std::string msg = fmt::vformat("The answer is {} so don't {}", ds);
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like this is possible without making changes to the fmt library.  `fmt::format` calls `fmt::vformat` which takes a `fmt::format_args` or `fmt::wformat_args` object representing multiple arguments, but the only ways provided to create `format_args` or `wformat_args` objects are via another variadic function, which means the number and types of the arguments must be known at compile time.

So you could write a wrapper to unpack a `std::tuple` or `std::array` and pass its elements to `fmt::format`, because the number and types of elements in those is known at compile time.  But you can't do the same with a `std::vector`, `std::list`, etc., since the size of those containers can vary at runtime.